# keep negative number in string negative when converted golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to extract LAT / LONG from a string, but my negative float for the longitude keeps changing to zero, so far I have:

loc1 := "33.333333"

loc2 := "-44.44444"

However when using the strvconv package my results:

```
nloc1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(loc1, 64)

RESULT: 33.333333 (successful float64)


nloc2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(loc2, 64)

RESULT: 0 (successful float64)
```

any ideas on how to stop that from going to zero? I need to keep it the same number just a negative float. Thanks in advance!

EDIT::  The issue was a leading space, once reformatted, it works as it should. Thanks all.

Comment: I don't get 0 when doing `strconv.ParseFloat(loc2, 64)` on your `loc2`; I get `-44.44443893432617`. Not sure what is going on....

Comment: It works [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RIOGEIFu4Sx). I suspect that one of the inputs is not what you think it is.  The error returns from ParseFloat will probably explain what's going on.

Comment: Does the error have anything useful? It's likely the input is malformed.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when you have leading or trailing whitespaces.

Try this:

```
nloc2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(strings.TrimSpace(loc2), 64)
```